# Vue equivalent for the ReactPlayer component

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, html5-video, react-player

I've been using the [ReactPlayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) component in the past and was wondering if there is a Vuejs equivalent to it?

I found [this](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-video-player), but this component doesn't seem to be maintained anymore + doesn't have all the functionalities of ReactPlayer.

Comment: Posted to Reddit and SO?
https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/tuoev1/vue_equivalent_for_the_reactplayer_component/

Comment: You can do this fairly easily natively / HTML 5 using [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), so you should just be able to wrap that in your own Player component. But if you really want to use something pre-built, there's [SevenOutman/vue-aplayer](https://github.com/SevenOutman/vue-aplayer) for audio and [Plyr](https://plyr.io/) / [redxtech/vue-plyr](https://github.com/redxtech/vue-plyr) for video.

Comment: @Alicia Thank you for the links, I ended up using HTML5 as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone developed a Vue clone of the react player: [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@voltra/vue-player). I haven't tested it though.